# Finding rank in a set

Tags: permutations

I have a set of four numbers.

A = {10, 8, 11, 2}

I have to find the rank of a number in the above set. Please help me in writing a suitable mathematical equation for finding the rank of a given number.

for ex: rank of 8 in the above array is '2'. rank of 11 is '4'.

Thanks Sincerely,
Ram.

Comment: I am assuming by your examples that rank is the number of elements in the set that are smaller or equal to a given number

Comment: Not exactly. I'm sorry for not providing clear info. My idea is finding the

Comment: Not exactly. I have to find the order of the number. As shown in the example, rank of '2' is 1. Terms I used here do not reflect the actual mathematical meaning.

Comment: According to @User666x way of defining the rank function, the rank of '2' is 1. So If this definition is not correct, Ram, then please provide a more elaborate example or a detailed definition of what you want the "rank" or "order" function to be.

Comment: Can you tell the  number as a specific formula for rank doesnt exist.

Comment: OK I think I understand. Then the set I provided you should give this answer, if you talk about the order of elements in the set from smallest to biggest

Answer (score 0):

Let $a\in A$. Then $Rank(a)=|\{b\in A: b\leq a\}|$ where |.| is the number or cardinality of elements in the set.

Comment: This has helped me in solving the problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Ram you are welcome